# Get Windows user credentials with windows authorization disabled in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is it possible to grab a users windows credentials (i.e. username) without having windows authentication enabled in IIS?  With windows auth disabled the code below returns either NT AUTHORITY or IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 depending on if impersonation and anonymous authentication are enabled or not.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

I am converting an asp.net web application that is using forms authentication to custom authentication.  Basically if a user is connecting from outside the network I force a credential check whereas if they are connecting from within the network I would like to be able to just grab their windows username.  The internal portion works when I turn on windows authentication but I get the popup login box when testing outside of the network.  I either need to disable windows authentication for non local connections or figure out how to get the windows username with windows authentication disabled.  Any suggestions?  (The other alternative i thought of was splitting the application in two and having separate authentication modes for each but I'd like to avoid this).

-I have also tried:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.ToString();
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this *is* actually (kind of) possible using Active Directory Federated Services. In the event of a windows user from inside the network they can be configured to use their account details. For external users, they can be redirected to a page that will require them to log in.

However. This is very heavy-duty and an extreme pain in the..neck to implement and is really only applicable to enterprise solutions that have the resourses to use this kind of solution. Otherwise, I'd say go with the 2 site approach.

Comment: I kinda figured I was going to need to use the 2 site approach, just hoping there might be another solution.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no.

Best solution is to create 2 sites. One for internal users that user windows authentication, one for external user that user forms authentication but authenticate against AD. You can make users always go to external site by default and then redirect based on their IP. That is redirect intranet users to internal user.